# lower_bound lambda comparison error

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Trying to use a lambda as a `Comp arg` within a `lower_bound` func, with no luck. I would like to use a lambda with `lower_bound std` func. It seems like wrong args cause the error. Below min example to reproduce an issue. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>> vertical(2);
    vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>> horizontal(2);
    for (auto& h : horizontal)
    {
        auto it = std::lower_bound(vertical.begin(), vertical.end(), h,
            [](vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>>::iterator it, vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>>::iterator sec) -> bool { return it->first < sec->second.first; });
    }
}
```

**Erorr**

> error C2664: 'bool
>   main::::operator
>   ()(std::_Vector_iterator>>,std::_Vector_iterator>>)
>   const': cannot convert argument 1 from
>   'std::pair>' to 
>   'std::_Vector_iterator>>' 1> 
>   with 1>        [ 1>            _Ty=std::pair>
>   1>        ]

Comment: whoever voted to close why is that so? what is wrong with this question?

Comment: what's wrong with what you have? Does it throw an error? Which one? Does it run, but return an unexpected output? If so, which one, and which would you expect?

Comment: I didn't vote. But one glaring issue is that you didn't post what error you get. It needs to be part of the question. There's also missing include directives, and your code is kinda hard to read.

Comment: Have a look at the definition of the predicate function here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound - it takes the actual container's type, not the iterator as arguments

Comment: Now with the error added, this is actually a decent signpost IMO.